# What is the precise relationship between projective duality and the Radon transform?

Tags: d-modules, projective-varieties

The Radon transform I am referring to is the one appearing in Brylinski's paper on projective duality, using the incidence correspondence over projective space and its dual projective space, $R p_{2*} p_1^*(K^{\cdot})[-n+1]$ in the derived category of constructible sheaves.  Mostly I would like to know:

1. To what extent this transform can be considered as a generalization of classical projective duality (can we compute a piece of the Radon transform of a constant sheaf restricted to a subvariety $V \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ in terms of its projective dual).
2. Assuming 1, to what extent there is interaction with other instances of projective duality, such as the theory of discriminants for varieties.